# How can I tell if Javascript is loading on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using Advanced custom Fields Accordion as a repeater.  I found a website that provided the javascript to use to make it work and it works on the site - https://wpbeaches.com/create-an-acf-repeater-accordion-in-wordpress/ and also works on codepen - https://codepen.io/lpjjonline/pen/WNyLJvM  when I tried it there but I can't get it to work on my site.

Javascript -

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
  to highlight the button that controls the panel */
  this.classList.toggle("active");

  /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
  var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (panel.style.display === "block") {
  panel.style.display = "none";
   } else {
  panel.style.display = "block";
   }
   });
   }

CSS - 

.accordion {
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
border: none;
outline: none;
transition: 0.4s;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border: none;
}
.accordion .active, .accordion:hover,
button:focus {
background-color: #ccc;
background: #ccc;
border: none;
}
.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
background-color: white;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
}
.accordion:after {
content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
font-size: 13px;
color: #777;
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;
}
.accordion .active:after {
content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

HTML/PHP -

<div class="faqs">
<?php 
// check for rows (parent repeater)
if( have_rows('faqs') ): ?>
                
<?php 
// loop through rows (parent repeater)
while( have_rows('faqs') ): the_row(); ?>
                 
<h2><?php if( get_sub_field('faq_department_name') ): ?>
<?php the_sub_field('faq_department_name'); ?>
<?php endif; ?></h2>
                       
<?php 
// check for rows (sub repeater)
if( have_rows('qas') ): ?>
 <ul>
 <?php 
// loop through rows (sub repeater)
 while( have_rows('qas') ): the_row();
```

// display each item as a list - with a class of completed ( if completed )

```
 ?>
                                
<li>

<button class="accordion"><?php if( get_sub_field('faq_question') ): ?>
<?php the_sub_field('faq_question'); ?>
<?php endif; ?></button>
<div class="panel"><?php if( get_sub_field('faq_answer') ): ?>
<?php the_sub_field('faq_answer'); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

</li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif;                         
endwhile; 
endif; ?>

</div>
```

All of the code is on the tutorial site and the codepen link.

The website that it's not working on is - https://collier.tfm-dev.com/township/faq/

My theme has this in the header - .

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you look at your console and network tabs in the browser dev tools (F12) you'll see your accordion script call has a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: Thank you Andy!  I just realized I removed the file from the header.  I just added it back in so it's not showing a 404 anymore but still not working.  Do you see any reason why it wouldn't be working?

Comment: Can you defer the `<script>` or add it to end of the page just before the `</body>` tag to allow the DOM to load first?